# geometric proof of $2\cos{A}\cos{B}=\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have seen geometric proof of identities
$$\cos{(A+B)}=\cos{A}\cos{B}-\sin{A}\sin{B}$$
and
$$\cos{(A-B)}=\cos{A}\cos{B}+\sin{A}\sin{B}$$

By adding two equation, $$2\cos{A}\cos{B}=\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)}$$.

But how to prove this by geometry?

Thank you.

Comment: If $\cos{(A+B)}=\cos{A}\cos{B}-\sin{A}\sin{B}$ and
$\cos{(A-B)}=\cos{A}\cos{B}+\sin{A}\sin{B}$ were proven geometrically, doesn't that mean you have already shown $2\cos{A}\cos{B}=\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)}$ geometrically?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
2 \cos A \cos B &= \cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B) \\[6pt]
2 \sin A \,\sin B &= \cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)
\end{align}$$

**Note.** Although not labeled (yet), these identities are also evident:

$$\begin{align}
2 \,\sin A \cos B &= \sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B) \\[6pt]
2 \cos A \,\sin B &= \sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)
\end{align}$$