# Trigonometric identity proof $\cos(A) + \cos( B)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is a nice proof of $$\cos(A) + \cos( B)= 2\cos\Big(\frac{A+B}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{A+B}{2}\Big)$$? 
I can prove it starting with the RHS but i want to be able to quickly prove it starting on the LHS as I won't have access to a formula book when I need it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are allowed to use the cosine-of-a-sum formula?

Comment: Yes i dont think i could forget that one if i wanted to

Comment: You may also find the half-angle formula $\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}$ useful.

Comment: Maybe write $\cos(A)=\cos(A+B-B)$ and $\cos(B)=\cos(A+B-A)$ and unpack it from there?

Comment: Do you know the identity $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$?

Comment: Yes that's the reason why im looking for this proof. Need to add roots of unity in exponential form

Comment: yes that works, i changed (a+b-b) to (a+b/2 + a-b/2) though, works out a bit easier

Comment: With a change of variables, [this answer has a picture proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165439/409).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y- \sin x\sin y$$

$$\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y$$

$$\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)=2\cos(x)\cos(y)$$

Now let $x+y=A$, $x-y=B$ and you'll get $$\cos A+\cos B=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast and efficient way forward.  We use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to write

$$\cos A+\cos B=\text{Re}\left(e^{iA}+e^{iB}\right) \tag 1$$

Now, simply factor out $e^{i(A+B)/2}$ under the "Real Part" operator in $(1)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}\text{Re}\left(e^{iA}+e^{iB}\right) &=\text{Re}\left(e^{i(A+B)/2}\left(e^{i(A-B)/2}+e^{-i(A-B)/2}\right)\right) \\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)e^{i(A+B)/2}\right) \\\\
&=2\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: This is a great solution. It took me a very long time to realize how to do this with Euler's formula. I kept trying to solve this while fully expanding each cosine into the real representation. Leaving it in the complex plane and taking the real part later is a great solution. +1

Comment: @akozi Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: start from
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$$
$$\cos(A-B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$$

Comment: Sorry i just realised my mistake there, made a typo in the question. I want a proof from the LHS

Answer (score 1):

From LHS to RHS:

$$
\cos B + \cos A \\
\cos \frac {2 B} 2 + \cos \frac {2 A} 2 \\
\cos\left(\frac {A + B - A + B} 2 \right) + \cos\left(\frac {A + B + A - B} 2 \right) \\
\cos\left(\frac {A + B} 2 - \frac {A - B} 2 \right) + \cos\left(\frac {A + B} 2 + \dfrac {A - B} 2 \right) \\
\left[\cos\left(\frac{A + B} 2\right)\cos\left(\frac{A - B} 2 \right) + \sin\left(\frac{A + B} 2 \right)\sin\left(\frac{A - B} 2 \right)\right] + \left[\cos\left(\frac{A + B} 2 \right)\cos\left(\frac{A - B} 2 \right) - \sin\left(\frac{A + B} 2 \right)\sin\left(\frac{A - B} 2 \right)\right]\\
2 \cos\left(\frac {A + B} 2 \right) \cos\left(\frac {A - B} 2 \right) \\
$$