# Additions of sines.

Tags: trigonometry

What would these expressions evaluate to and why? A proof would be appreciated.

$$\sin(A) ± \sin(B)$$
$$\cos(A) ± \cos(B)$$

If there’s anything else I should know, please inform me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using Euler’s formula?

Comment: You might find useful the [Wikipedia list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165439/409https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165439/409).

Answer (score 1):

If you solve $\left\{\begin{array}{c} A = u+v \\ B = u-v \end{array}\right\}$ for $u$ and $v$, you get 
$\left\{
   \begin{array}{c} 
      u = \frac{A+B}{2} \\ 
      v = \frac{A-B}{2} \end{array}
 \right\}$.

So
\begin{align}
   \sin A + \sin B 
      &= \sin(u+v) + \sin(u-v) \\
      &= (\sin u \ \cos v + \cos u \ \sin v) + 
         (\sin u \ \cos v - \cos u \ \sin v) \\
      &= 2 \sin u \ \cos v \\
      &= 2 \sin \frac{A+B}{2} \ \cos \frac{A-B}{2} \\
\end{align}

The other formulas are computed similarly.